# how to send files as attachment in email in magento for downloadable products?

Tags: email, magento, attachment, product

I am new to Magento. I am working on a web site which is selling downloadable products.
My client want purchased products should be sent via email in attachment?
Currently, I am developing in localhost so I am not sure whether magneto actually send product files in email or not?
Should I need to enable any option for that in configuration?

Comment: :- same question here !! if you find the solution then please let me know

Comment: Go to configuration->catalog->downloadable->attachment= inline. This actually doesn't attach files with email but send it as link. When customer click it, file will be downloaded. Thus Magento controls it, if order status is not 'completed' then file cannot be downloaded.

Comment: can we also set expiration of that link also ? if yes, then how ?

Comment: No, But you can set maximum number downloads for any link.

Answer (score 0):

---

If you want to develop this at your localhost keep in mind, that you have to set up mail server or use some solutions from community like below link, to send it by gmail and other:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

You also can just configure your server to save mails without sending.
So you'll be able to review it.

Good article about how to send downloadable by email here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49511/how-can-i-get-only-the-downloadable-product-url-in-email-template

But!!! keep in mind that the latest Magento use queue to send email (which runs by cron), so if you have such a distribution (for example 1.9+) you need to adjust code which you have from link above.

Here istwo solutions for this case:

Disable adding email to queue after order.
Just comment this part of code in "Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template"'s "send()" method:

```
//        if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
        /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
       /* $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
        $emailQueue->clearRecipients();
        $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
        $emailQueue->setMessageParameters(array(
                'subject'           => $subject,
                'return_path_email' => $returnPathEmail,
                'is_plain'          => $this->isPlain(),
                'from_email'        => $this->getSenderEmail(),
                'from_name'         => $this->getSenderName(),
                'reply_to'          => $this->getMail()->getReplyTo(),
                'return_to'         => $this->getMail()->getReturnPath(),
            ))
            ->addRecipients($emails, $names, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_TO)
            ->addRecipients($this->_bccEmails, array(), Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_BCC);
        $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();

        return true;
    }*/
```

So emails will be sent immediately (be aware, that if you have very big turnover with spikes it can create performance issue)

Second way is to save full path of attachment to table "core_email_queue" field - "message_parameters". You can do it adding url to array of argument here `$emailQueue->setMessageParameters(` in code above.
After that you can handle it in "Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue"'s "send()" method
using standard "Zend Mail"'s method - "createAttachment()". Below link provides deeper explanation of this part.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/magento-send-file-attachements-in-emails

Hope it will help sombody.
Have a good day!!!